# Can't get basic Kotlin coroutine examples to work in Windows console

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm experimenting with Kotlin. Testing via Android is slow and fiddly so I'm trying to just using the Windows console version. This seems to be less well documented.

Basic hello world worked fine so I moved onto [the first coroutine example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,")
    Thread.sleep(2000L)
}
```

I'm using Kotlin 1.3.50 and I downloaded kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.0.jar and put it in the same directly as my soucre file.

I build it with:
`kotlinc kotlintest.kt -cp kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.0.jar -include-runtime`

I attempt to run it with:
`kotlin KotlintestKt`

I get this error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/GlobalScope
        at KotlintestKt.main(kotlintest.kt:4)
        at KotlintestKt.main(kotlintest.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:61)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:110)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 9 more
```

There are similar questions but answers seem to only go into Gradle or IntelliJ IDEA, which I'm not using. I have basically no prior experience with Java or Kotlin but decades of hobby programming experience.

Comment: The compiler needs access to the coroutines jar file to know if the classes you're using exist, which methods they have, etc., and thus be able to check if your code is correct, and generate byte-code. That's why you pass `-cp kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.0.jar`. Similarly, at runtime, the JVM needs access to the coroutines jar file to be able to execute the code that the classes contain. But you don't pass any classpath when executing your code. So it can't find them. So you get that exception.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks. As I mention at the bottom of my question I have no Java experience and none of the Kotlin on Windows stuff I've followed has talked about "classpath". I'll see if I can figure it out...

Comment: @AjahnCharles: Now I can't even compile: `warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: kotlin-coroutines-core-1.3.0.jar
kotlintest.kt:4:5: error: unresolved reference: GlobalScope`

Comment: @JBNizet: This seems to work: `kotlin -cp kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.0.jar;. KotlintestKt` though I don't really understand why the `;.` is needed but wasn't before I put the coroutine stuff in there. Maybe because the coroutine lib is in the same directory??

Comment: If you don't specify the classpath, it defaults to the current directory. So it could find your class (which is in the current directory), but not the coroutines classes (which are not in the current directory, but in a jar file). If you specify a classpath, then it looks for classes in that specified classpath. You need the jar in the classpath because your code uses classes from that jar, and you need the current  directory in the classpath becuase your own class is in the current directory, and needs to be found and executed, too.